# File Resource in .Net Core app?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm using .Net Core 1.1. Trying to embed a text file resource and I get (on Resource.TextFile1):

> TextFile1.txt;System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089;Windows-1252

On regular .Net, it would give me the whole text file as a string.

I've search on SO and Google and I saw some old responses that don't really work anymore. With ILSpy the resource isn't in the binary at all. If I add:

```
    "embed":
    {
        "includeFiles":
        [
            "TextFile1.txt"
        ]
    }
```

Then it gets embedded, but in a different namespace than the string and it seems like I have to manually read it out of the binary. Is there any easier / better way to do this?